# Java generics - returning a list of generic successor

Tags: java, generics, extends

What is the differnece between

```
public static <T extends MyObj> ArrayList<T> generateRandomList(int count);
```

and

```
public static ArrayList<? extends MyObj> generateRandomList(int count);
```

Because they behave diffenerently.

the first option fails to compile the following line

```
ArrayList<MyObjSuccessor> myObj = Util.generateRandomList(2);
```

The second options causes my call to compile.

Comment: What is the return type of Util.generateRandomList?

Comment: What error message did you get with the first option? That is usually a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `MyObjSuccessor extends MyObj`...

- The displayed invocation of your **second** method (using parametrized wildcard) will not compile, because of type erasure, unless you cast the invocation as an `ArrayList<MyObjSuccessor>` (at your own risk).
- Also both methods cannot cohabitate within the same `Util` class, because they have the same signature.

Comment: The first one compiles but you can't really put anything in the list.

Comment: @biziclop actually my answer is ambiguous, thanks for bringing my attention to this. Will edit now.

Comment: @biziclop why couldn't you? It's a List<T>: you can add any T you want (i.e. any MyObjSuccessor in this case).

Comment: @JBNizet Except there's nothing of type `T` coming in that you can add. You can't instantiate `T` either. So while the method compiles, it's practically useless without explicit casts, which break type-safety.

Comment: You can't add anything from inside the method (except null), but the caller of the method can add any MyObjSuccessor object to the returned list.

Comment: @JBNizet Imagine that `MyObj` is `Number`. Both `ArrayList<Integer> foo = Util.generateRandomList(2)` and `ArrayList<Double> foo = Util.generateRandomList(2)` will compile, yet because of type erasure the method itself has no way of knowing which case is happening.

Comment: @JBNizet That's what I meant, yes. I just inferred from the name `generateRandomList()` that it is supposed to return something other than an empty list.